# Not able to update-database with Code First Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: entity-framework

In my project I am using code first and I was able to create my database and apply migrations to it via the nuget package manager console.

Now I added a second database context to my application and this context is not code first. this context is built on an existing database.

after adding the second context ... if I try to do a update-database, I get an error

```
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
System.NotSupportedException: Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel.
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
```

However, I ONLY want to apply migrations to my first context and want the second context to be left alone.

Comment: Maybe you have to specify your db context when updating. Write parameter behind update-database command.

Comment: thanks your suggestion worked. I have documented my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by directly specifying the Configuration type to be updated

update-database -ConfigurationTypeName Company.Project.Migrations.MySpecificConfiguration

This article helped a lot

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html